# How to insert into multiple tables in a single statement in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

All the tables are of the same structure,does MySQL support this kind of operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, it doesn't..............

Answer (score 2):

You can do multi-table updates, but not inserts, in a single statement.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, but you could execute two (or more!) statements within a single transaction, thus treating the two operations as a single atomic operation.  However, by default your database is most likely auto-committing after each statement, thus making a separate transaction for each executed statement.  Refer to the manual's section on [START TRANSACTION, COMMIT, and ROLLBACK syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) for more information on how to change this.

In general, though, I wouldn't recommend turning off auto-commit unless you're really sure you understand the implications of doing so.